# Why do I have to click twice to toggle() in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

**TLDR:** Why do I have to click twice to toggle my `.show` class on these divs?

I'm trying to get a hidden div to overlay other divs on mobile devices using a combined CSS grid and flex layout. I can get it to work on devices with a mouse using just CSS and `:hover`, but not on touch devices - obviously because there is no easy way to "hover" on a phone. I'm ok with using click events instead of hover on mobile.

I'm using jQuery because it's already loaded on the site for other reasons, but I'd be equally happy with a vanilla JS solution.

As far as I understand, I can't use `.show()` or `.hide()` or similar functions in jQuery because they effectively change the item to `display: block` and don't work with `display: flex` or `display: grid`. (Feel free to correct me).

I have no way of knowing how many divs the page might have in the end. I don't want *all* the hidden boxes to display on click, just the one indicated by matching the ID (ie, if I click `#some-id` then `#some-id-overlay` should pop up, not `#a-third-id-overlay` or anything else). This is why I am looping over each `.hover-target` and using a click event listener in the loop.

I want this to work on click as well as on hover - should I be wrapping my `.hover` part in something that tests for the presence of a mouse/pointing device? Or checking for viewport width, perhaps?

*I know the problem is something to do with having both on `click` and on `hover` - because if I remove the `hover()` part, the two-click problem goes away. I just don't know how to fix it :(*

Here is a simplified version of my code (live version at http://detailfactory.ie/newsite/):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hover-target").each(function() {
    // get the ID of each hover target
    var hoverID = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // string
    var hoverOverlay = jQuery('#' + hoverID + '-overlay'); // element

    /* if any hover target is CLICKED */
    jQuery(this).on("click", function() {
      hoverOverlay.toggleClass('show');
    }); // hover

    /* HOVER */
    jQuery(this).hover(function() {
      hoverOverlay.toggleClass('show');
    }); // hover

  }); // each

}); // document.ready
```

```css
.hover-target {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-target" id="some-id">a</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="some-id-overlay">aaa</div>

<div class="hover-target" id="another-id">b</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="another-id-overlay">bbb</div>

<div class="hover-target" id="a-third-id">c</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="a-third-id-overlay">ccc</div>
```

Comment: It would help if your snipped actually showed us what was happening :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise my partial code would create a snippet that would run:(

Comment: Whenever you click on something you first have to hover over it. So it toggles it once while you're hovering, then again when you click.

Comment: The reason for the hover/click issue is clicking requires you to hover on the object, which means that BOTH events will be triggered when clicking. You could remove the `click` event and still have it work since clicking technically requires you to hover over the object anyway.

Comment: @imvain2 I suspect he needs the click event for mobile devices, which don't have hover.

Comment: @imvain that's clever. If I remove the click event though, then then the overlays don't hide if you click again

Comment: @gillespieza, you could use `mouseout` or `mouseover`.

Comment: @imvain2 thanks - that gave me the idea to try `touchstart` and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use toggle in the hover handler. The hover method takes two functions, one for the enter action, the other for the leave action; add the class in the first, remove it in the second.

You can still toggle in the click handler. On mobile devices with no hover support, the hover code will be ignored.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hover-target").each(function() {
    // get the ID of each hover target
    var hoverID = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // string
    var hoverOverlay = jQuery('#' + hoverID + '-overlay'); // element

    /* if any hover target is CLICKED */
    jQuery(this).on("click", function() {
      hoverOverlay.toggleClass('show');
    }); // hover

    /* HOVER */
    jQuery(this).hover(function() {
      hoverOverlay.addClass('show');
    }, function() {
      hoverOverlay.removeClass('show');
    }); // hover

  }); // each

}); // document.ready
```

```css
.hover-target {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-target" id="some-id">a</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="some-id-overlay">aaa</div>

<div class="hover-target" id="another-id">b</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="another-id-overlay">bbb</div>

<div class="hover-target" id="a-third-id">c</div>
<div class="grid-item-overlay" id="a-third-id-overlay">ccc</div>
```

Comment: Although this doesn't fix any problem, you could also get rid of the loop altogether and instead of `hoverOverlay` use `$(this).next()`. That would simplify the code.

Comment: The overlays might not be the next sibling though. They could occur in any order.

Comment: @gillespieza you can still scrap the loop and just add `var hoverID = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // string
    var hoverOverlay = jQuery('#' + hoverID + '-overlay')` to each event handler. That outer loop isn't needed

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - but I still end up having to click twice on mobile devices?